# When does the narrowband model in array processing fail?

Tags: array-signal-processing

I am not sure that I understand well the narrowband assumption in array processing. I wonder how it simplifies the model and what would change if not assumed. Also, what will happen if I apply the model on signals that are not narrowband?

Comment: so, how *do* you  understand the narrowband assumption? We can't tell you whether you understand it correctly if you don't tell us *how* you understand it.

Comment: (also, this reads 100% like an exercise assignment: In that case, simply show what you've done so far, what your considerations are and where you're stuck)